# Most relevant literature on topology and modern geometry.

Tags: reference-request, math-history, reference-works

I’ve been collecting and reading some articles and publications of history’s most influential mathematicians from different sources, so i’ve got a clear historical picture of their work, their contributions and the mathematical tools they developed in their respective fields. I want to do the same with topology and modern geometry, but i do not know where to start (please, do not refer me to pedagogical textbooks). I’ve got “the foundations of geometry” from D. Hilbert. and some publications from Riemann… but aside from that, i do not have much clue on what else should i search for. Maybe go back to cantor’s publications? Skip them with some more recent article that covers a more general range of the subject? Maybe Poincaré?

Comment: Dieudonné, *A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology, 1900 - 1960*. You mentioned Cantor: did you mean point-set topology? If so, the early editions of Hausdorff’s *Mengelehre* were very influential. Weyl’s *The Concept of a Riemann Surface* redirected the field.

Comment: The mathematical texts of Poincaré aren't easy to read because notations have evolved, unlike its philosophical texts whose reading is a pleasure.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss, thanks. I’ll look for those references.